# Indexing tables jQuery

Tags: jquery, indexing, html-table

In this HTML page I have many tables...
I just need to assign an unique id to each row.

I have also a jQuery function that add and remove single rows:

```
<table id="tab_voce">
   <tr class="voce">
      <td>
         something1
      </td>
      <td>
         something2
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>

// add rows
$(document).on('click', '#add_row' , function() {
    $(add_row_string).appendTo(tab_voce);   
});
// index table
$(document).on('click' , '#index_row' , function(){
    var n_tr = $('#tab_1 tr').size()-1;
    $('tr.voce > td:first-child').text("voce_"+ n_tr);  //I cant fix the selector
                                                        //In this way it selects every <td> of every table
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify everything out to get what I believe you are trying to achieve.

The below creates new rows and also gets the current clicked row's id and outputs it. You can then use this ID for whatever you need it to do.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add_row', function() {
  var i = $('#tab_voce tr').length + 1;
  $('#tab_voce').append('<tr id="row_' + i + '" class="row"><td>New Row</td><td>New Row</td>');

});
$(document).on('click', '.row', function() {
  $('#clicked_row span').text($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab_voce">
  <tr id="row_1" class="row">
    <td>
      something1
    </td>
    <td>
      something2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="add_row">Add Row</button>
<div id="clicked_row">Clicked Row: <span></span>
</div>
```